# How get result of executed batch script as string in python?

Tags: python

I have code like this `os.system(mycommand)`. I want to get result of batch command  as string.How can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python's `subprocess` module has a [built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) to do this as of Python 2.7.

```
import subprocess

try:
  mycommand = "ls"
  result = subprocess.check_output(mycommand, shell=True)
  print(result)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as error:
  # Handle the error
  print("Error: Command exited with code {0}".format(error.returncode))
```